# How to buy Greek bonds either directly or via ETF?

Tags: investing, etf, bonds, greece

Is there an online brokerage, for UK citizens, that provides access to Greek bonds? [Interactive Brokers](http://www.interactivebrokers.co.uk/) doesn't.

Alternatively, are there other assets (say ETFs) that have a percentage invested in Greek bonds?

Answer (score 1):

NBG.gr has offices in london. So from there you could start asking